# Twitter integration with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, twitter

it seems SharePoint has a separate certificate store and doesn't utilize the built in one. With that said, we had trouble pulling facebook feeds within a SharePoint webpart until we manually added the facebook certificate to SharePoint. When we tried the same manual process of adding twitters cert to sharepoint we get the error "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure". Its the same error that we got when integrating facebook until we added facebooks cert to sharepoint. Do you know what might be happening.

More info:

1. We cant use the standard API due to rate limits, we have to authenticate.
2. The code work fine if NOT running within sharepoint.
3. We are using LinqToTwitter with ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, OAuthToken, and AccessToken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to add the certificate but use the following before using the API:

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate
    {

        return true;

    };
```